# Insert String timestamp into db having timestamp field

Tags: java, timestamp, prepared-statement

I am having a Timestamp in the following format as string.

```
Lifte_date="2013-10-21 00:00:00";
```

I need to insert it into a database having `Timestamp` type field using `PreparedStatement`. How to do it.?

Comment: You can convert string to `Timestamp` and insert

Comment: Can u pls give a sample code to insert the same using prepared statement?

Comment: @Leeza : the answer from the above link has all the code you need .

Comment: Thanks...it helped

Comment: can u pls say while using `prepared statement` which set type should be used for numeric filed type in db?

Comment: See types mappings here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-data-types.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot @Berger

Comment: That list is old, @Berger. These days one should prefer to use `java.time.Instant` for timestamps, according to what I read.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done like this

```
    String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER (TIME) VALUES(?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
    preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, your_time_stamp);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```